# Copying pointers data to byte array and writing to MemoryStream results to tons of allocation in LOH

Tags: c#

I have WPF app and using ffmpeg library. I have a video recording preview using `SDL2`. For SDL pixel format its used `PixelFormat_UYVY`, so every frame is converted to `YUV420P`.

Conversation is done with

```
        MemoryStream ms = null;

        using (ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int shift = 0;
            byte* yuv_factor;

            for (uint i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                shift = (i == 0 ? 0 : 1);
                yuv_factor = frame->data[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < (frame->height >> shift); j++)
                {
                    byte[] frameData = new byte[frame->width >> shift];
                    Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)yuv_factor, frameData, 0, frameData.Length);
                    yuv_factor += frame->linesize[i];

                    ms.Write(frameData, 0, frameData.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        return ms.ToArray();
```

Then this `byte[]` is simply casted to `IntPtr` and passed to `SDL`.

```
sdl.Preview((IntPtr)data);
```

The problem is that I can see tons of `GC Pressure` and a lot of `System.Byte[]` allocations in LOH. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: You can lower some GC pressure by renting byte arrays from the `ArrayPool` - just look at the documentation of `ArrayPool<T>` from the System.Buffers namespace. You esentially rent an array, use it and then return it to the pool.

Comment: Never heard of it before. Will try it, thanks!

Comment: If you're interested in more details, this [post](https://adamsitnik.com/Array-Pool/) from Adam is really interesting and might give some further insights.

Comment: The only issue would be if `Rent` returns array with bigger size than requested. This would mess up the preview

Comment: `ArrayPool<T>` might return a bigger array than requested (but at least the size you requested). One thing that might work: Reference the array using `Span<T>`, then slice the right part out of it using the `Slice` method and finally get the desired pointer and use something like `fixed(var arPointer = spanVariableName) { ... }` - But be aware of the fact, that you might eventually have to zero terminate stuff at the end of your sliced array if your low-level call needs something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you begin with analyzing the number of allocations in your code:

- `MemoryStream` which is essentially backed by an expanding byte array under the hood (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs)). I have seen something like a [recycleable version](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream) of it. That might help as well.
- As already suggested in the comment, renting an array using the `ArrayPool` might be an easy way to reduce memory very quickly, especially in case of the `frameData` array.
- As it seems, the `ToArray()` call at the end of your method also creates a new array (look at the implementation using the above link).

I would try to target these three spots first and then reevaluate.

Comment: well, `RecycleableMemoryStream` made huge difference. I'm amazed. Also, using `ms.GetBuffer()` instead of `ms.ToArray()`